# Adding a method to a singleton without modifying its class

Tags: c++, oop, singleton

I'm working with a code that has a singleton, I don't want to modify the class of the singleton to add a method "void Connect(const int port)", it will be identical to the singleton method "void Connect()" but will not show a dialog box to ask the user for the port number. This method updates the singleton private member's map... and I need that the new method updates this map too.

I thought of the "friend" keyword, but this last must be put inside the singleton class.

Inheritance won't work since I have to use the singleton from the derived class everywhere in the code (which is not mine).

What would you do in this situation ?

Comment: For us to answer, we'd need to know: _"I don't want to modify the class of the singleton to add a method"_ **why**?

Comment: @YSC Because my application is based on another project and I do not want to maintain the changes that I can make in this project.

Comment: can you make a [mcve]? Its easier to describe code with code rather than with words

Comment: @mkaes: Are you sure this question is unclear? We've got two answers with the same interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This (imho horribly bad) idea can actually be done.

1: Copy the header file.
2: Add the function definition to the end. This won't break linkage.
3: Add a .cpp file implementing it.

Comment: That's what I've done, it is not pretty but it works :\

Answer (score 2):

C++ does not allow methods to be added to an existing class like some other languages do.

If you want to do something that requires access to a 3rd party libraries private data, you really need to make that library provide something public. Even if its something like `void SetConnection(SOCKET sock)` and then 99% of your custom stuff can be separate. Any workaround to write to such a private member would not be standards compliant.

If it was `protected`, inheritance might work, but in the case of a singleton the library would need to provide a means for you to provide your own instance.

Assuming you get a suitable minimal public method in the library, then you may choose to use a free function (e.g. `void the_singleton_connect(int port)`) or you could make a wrapper singleton to use in your own code with the extra methods.

If you really want to go ahead and access a private member anyway, then remember that in C++ it is just the header file containing declarations anyway. So you can modify it or make your own compatible declaration for the class. This could be a macro to change `private` to `public`, you could edit the file to make that member public, add `friend`, add extra methods, etc. just leave the member variables exactly the same so as to not change the memory layout.